# Two tables: order and order_status. Relationship or enum type? What kind of relationshi

Tags: data-modeling, relationship

I have two tables: `order` and `order_status`.

In the first one I store the orders of a shop and in the second one the different possible statuses that an order can have (in progress, paid, ...).

Should be there a relationship (1:1??) between these two tables or should I just create an ENUM type for the status values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go ahead and create the table.  You will need more statuses over time (trust me, I work on 20,000 online stores every day, and OrderStatus is NOT as simple as it sounds).  This will also let you add flags the statuses: some answers may count as a form of "shipped", even if their descriptions vary.

Comment: Thanks, but what kind of relationship is it? 1:1?

Comment: Each order has one status (at any given time, at least).  Each status can be used by any number of orders.  So that's many-to-one.

Answer (score 0):

I usually do enum type for the status values.  This way I don't have to hit the database each time I want to do a lookup for a dropdown etc.